# Adding labels next to lines at a fixed distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to animate a weighted graph created using TikZ, emphasizing each edge once (temporarily setting the line width to thick). The problem is that the edge weights jump when changing the line width. To prevent edge weights from jumping, I duplicate each edge. The first copy uses a thin line width, has a label, and is always drawn on the background. The second copy uses a thick line width, has no label, and is drawn only on some slides.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (2) at (1,0) {2}
      edge node [auto] {1} (1)
      edge [thick] (1);
  \node (3) at (1,1) {3}
      edge node [auto] {2} (2)
      edge [thick] (2);
  \node (4) at (0,1) {4}
      edge node [auto] {3} (3)
      edge node [auto, swap] {4} (1)
      edge [thick] (3)
      edge [thick] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a better solution that does not duplicate each edge?

Comment: You might want to explain how you do the animation and provide a complete MWE. Just guessing from the term "slides" in your question, you may want to have a look at the aobs package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strategy is already quite good, I think. I would personally use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library for that. This allows you also to draw the edge just once, using `thick on` which I created for that purpose. <s>I do not see any jumps.</s> As pointed out by @Max Snippe, there are tiny jumps in my previous solution. Given that, I still believe your original idea is among the most economic proposals. I added another one for comparison.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{
    thick on/.style={alt={#1{thick}{thin}}},
    ultra thick on/.style={alt={#1{line width=3mm}{thin}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An animation with the overlay-beamer-styles library}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (2) at (1,0) {2}
      edge node [auto] {1} (1)
      edge [thick,visible on=<1>] (1);
  \node (3) at (1,1) {3}
      edge node [auto] {2} (2)
      edge [thick,visible on=<2>] (2);
  \node (4) at (0,1) {4}
      edge node [auto] {3} (3)
      edge node [auto, swap] {4} (1)
      edge [thick,visible on=<3>] (3)
      edge [thick,visible on=<4>] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (2) at (1,0) {2}
      edge [thick on=<1>] (1) (2) --(1) node [midway,auto]{1} ;
  \node (3) at (1,1) {3}
      edge [thick,thick on=<2>] (2) (3) -- node [midway,auto] {2} (2);
  \node (4) at (0,1) {4}
      edge [thick,thick on=<3>] (3) 
      edge [thick,thick on=<4>] (1) 
      (4) -- node [midway,auto] {3} (3)
      (4) -- node [midway,auto, swap] {4} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (2) at (1,0) {2}
      edge [ultra thick on=<1>] (1) (2) --(1) node [midway,auto]{1} ;
  \node (3) at (1,1) {3}
      edge [ultra thick,ultra thick on=<2>] (2) (3) -- node [midway,auto] {2} (2);
  \node (4) at (0,1) {4}
      edge [ultra thick,ultra thick on=<3>] (3) 
      edge [ultra thick,ultra thick on=<4>] (1) 
      (4) -- node [midway,auto] {3} (3)
      (4) -- node [midway,auto, swap] {4} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The third pic is just for illustration that there are no jumps.

Comment: The jumps are still visible with this solution, because Tikz apparently placed the edge nodes relative to the outer edge of the lines. With the `decorations.pathreplacing` library you can change your `thick on` style to: `thick on/.style={line width=0.4pt,alt={#1{decoration={show path construction, lineto code={\draw[thick] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);}},decorate}{}}}`. Note that this only works for straight lines.

Comment: @MaxSnippe Thanks a lot! I am still not convinced one should go the decoration way, it makes the code rather long. But please feel free to write your answer. ;-)

Comment: I agree that the code with decorations is quite long. Could you explain why adding the `midway` key solves the small jumps? This way your solution is definitely superior.

Comment: @MaxSnippe It is not any superior to the OP's suggestion, I think. I also draw the edge twice, once with the edge syntax, and then with the normal `--` syntax. I also believe that, given enough motivation, one could find more elaborate ways. But I personally prefer simple understandable pieces of codes that even not-so-experienced users can customize of some some very elaborate things that could break easily. After all, `auto` does already a very good job, just not in this animation.

Comment: Must've overlooked that you also draw the lines twice. I will add my answer as an alternative, because the OP explicitly asks for a solution for that. (I do agree that simpler is often better.)

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with @marmot that most of the time a simpler solution is better, I will add this answer as an alternative because it is possible to do it by drawing the edge only once (with a rather tedious decoration). This solution does need the `decorations.pathreplacing` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
    thick on/.style={line width=0.4pt,alt={#1{decoration={show path construction, lineto code={\draw[thick] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);}},decorate}{}}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An animation with the overlay-beamer-styles library}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node (2) at (1,0) {2}
        edge node [auto] {1} (1)
        edge [thick] (1);
    \node (3) at (1,1) {3}
        edge node [auto] {2} (2)
        edge [thick] (2);
    \node (4) at (0,1) {4}
        edge node [auto] {3} (3)
        edge node [auto, swap] {4} (1)
        edge [thick] (3)
        edge [thick] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node (2) at (1,0) {2};
    \node (3) at (1,1) {3};
    \node (4) at (0,1) {4};
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={auto,swap,midway}]
        \draw[thick on=<1>] (1) -- node{1} (2);
        \draw[thick on=<2>] (2) -- node{2} (3);
        \draw[thick on=<3>] (3) -- node{3} (4);
        \draw[thick on=<4>] (4) -- node{4} (1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```